# When redirecting to another domain, to which domain should I apply HSTS?

Tags: ssl, redirect, hsts

old.example.com redirects to new.example.com as follows

```
http://old.example.com > https://new.example.com
https://old.example.com > https://new.example.com
http://www.old.example.com > https://new.example.com
```

One which one should I apply HSTS?

I'm using Cloudflare to do the redirects.

Thanks!

Comment: to your new domain would be fine enough, it wouldnt make any big difference if you'd apply it to all. Meaning if you access the old domain on http, you'll get redirected to https, and therefore you get redirected to new domain.
Edit: typo

Answer (score 1):

Using plain HTTP instead of HTTPS is vulnerable to man in the middle attacks which might be used for malicious redirects like described in [Sandvine’s PacketLogic Devices Used to Deploy Government Spyware in Turkey and Redirect Egyptian Users to Affiliate Ads?](https://citizenlab.ca/2018/03/bad-traffic-sandvines-packetlogic-devices-deploy-government-spyware-turkey-syria/). The goal should be therefore to reduce the use of plain HTTP as much as possible.

The redirects you have installed are specific for a specific URL only, i.e. domain, path and query string. Even a permanent redirect (HTTP status code 301) will only mean that the browser will automatically visit the newly given URL for this specific old URL, i.e. a redirect seen on `http://old.example.com/` will not have any effect on `http://old.example.com/foo`. Thus each new URL visited on the old domain with plain HTTP offers a new opportunity for the attacker.

HSTS instead is specific to a whole domain and optionally even its subdomains. A HSTS issued for `http://old.example.com/` will be taken into consideration on a later visit to `http://old.example.com/foo` and result in the browser visiting `https://old.example.com/foo` directly without even trying plain HTTP. From there one can then safely redirect to `https://new.example.com/foo`.

Therefore using HSTS on the old domain is recommended, since it also protects future redirects from the old domain to the new one. It is also recommended to use `includeSubDomains` to protect also redirects from the old subdomains, but in this case you would also need to have valid certificates on the subdomains.